# Filter dictionaries and nested dictionaries for key

Tags: python

I want to solve the following problem without introducing several if/else if cases. I have the following dictionaries:

```py
dict_1 = {"full_name": {"name": "Foo", "surname": "Bar"}, "age": 29, "test": 0}
dict_2 = {"name": "Foo", "age": 29, "test": 1}
```

Now, I want to receive the value of the key "name" for both dictionaries. In the "real" program situation, I don't know if a structure of `dict_1` or `dict_2` will be present, but in all structures that will be present, the key "name" will exist. So I need a function like the following:

```py
filter_dict_for_key(dict, key):
...
   return val(key)
```

For both dictionaries, I expect the output "Foo".
Is there an elegant pythonic way to do this with filter/dict comprehension, etc.?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it? What if there's more than one `name` key somewhere in the tree?

Comment: If it's nested, is it always in the `full_name` key?

Comment: Do you really need a general-purpose filtering function for this? Can any key be nested? Can there be multiple levels of nesting? In the latter case, use a recursive function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried a filtering approach like `index_list = list(filter(lambda entry: "name" in entry.keys(), input_list))` but could not solve the problem with nested appearances

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it is always in the `full_name`key. But I don't know, at what level.

Comment: So it could be something like `{'full_name': { 'full_name': {'name': "foo" }}}`?

Comment: @Barmar No, but it could be something like `{'x': { 'full_name': {'name': "foo" }}}`, so the instance above `"name"` would always be `"full_name"`

Comment: What did you mean by "I don't know at what level"? It's either at the top-level or nested immediately inside the full_name key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive function is usually the easiest way to handle an arbitrarily nested object.  Since there's always the possibility of there being more (or fewer) than one matching item, this function returns a list of matches:

```
>>> def get_name_nested(d):
...     """Return a list of all 'name' values in a nested dict."""
...     if not isinstance(d, dict):
...         return []
...     if 'name' in d:
...         return [d['name']]
...     return [n for s in d.values() for n in get_name_nested(s)]
...
>>> get_name_nested({"full_name": {"name": "Foo", "surname": "Bar"}, "age": 29, "test": 0})
['Foo']
>>> get_name_nested({"name": "Foo", "age": 29, "test": 1})
['Foo']
```

If you need to handle additional types of nesting (e.g. a list of dicts or a list of lists which may themselves be nested), it's pretty straightforward to extend this approach to handle those.

Comment: For my use case, this works as intended. Thank you @Samwise

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default argument to `dict.get()`

```
name = mydict.get('name', mydict.get('full_name', {}).get('name'))
```

So if there's no `name` key in the top-level, it looks in the `full_name` key. You have to use `.get()` for the default in case there's no `full_name` key.

Or use a conditional expression:

```
name = mydict['name'] if 'name' in mydict else mydict['full_name']['name']
```

Note that this will get an error if neither key exists. You can use `try/except` to catch that if necessary.